# PHP: if(!$one == $two) doesn't work always?

Tags: php, operators, operator-precedence

Yes, this is just a question i would like to get an answer on. I experienced it a couple of times, where this:

```
if(!$one == $two){ echo "Not the same"; }else{ echo "The same"; }
```

Will not work, and

```
if($one == $two){ echo "The same"; }else{ echo "Not the same"; }
```

will work.

Why doesn't it work sometimes? I always need to recode like the second, when the first doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!` is having higher [`precedence`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than `==` so you should use parenthesis as:

```
if(!($one == $two))
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to write

```
if(!($one == $two))
```

or

```
if($one != $two)
```

since the ! operator has a higher precedence than the == operator.

See also: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
if(!($one == $two))
```

This is because without the brackets, it is checking if $one is false and then checking if $two == $one.  The following is the only time that it will work without the brackets.  Evaluating to if (true == true) as !$one = true.

```
$one = false;
$two = true;

if (!$one == $two)
{
    echo "different";
}
```